# xsd - How to handle attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I handle the attribute of an element?
For example when validation has an value, then the attribute valid should be required.
If the tag is empty like in the second datapoint, then it should be optional.

How can I realize this in xsd?

Example

```
        <dataPoint type="DatapointCurrent">
            <description>Measured current</description>
            <dataType>Float</dataType>
            <validatio valid="LOW">1</validation>
            <validationRange min="-3.0" max="5.0"/>
        </dataPoint>
        <dataPoint type="DatapointVoltage">
            <description>Measured voltage</description>
            <dataType>Float</dataType>
            <validation/>
            <validationRange/>
        </dataPoint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 there is no way of making the rules for the content of an element depend in any way on the value of its attributes.

In XSD 1.1 this can be achieved either with assertions (a very general mechanism) or with the more specific mechanism of conditional type attribution (aka type alternatives).

Using assertions your rule would be

```
<xs:assert test="if (. != '') then exists(@valid) else true()"/>
```

Comment: Hey Michael,thanks for your answer! I'm not quite sure where to put it into my check. I put my solution how I try to realize it in my question. But where should i put the assert?

Comment: I tried to put it in the restriction before the enumeration. But then this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I tried again and now it works. Theres just one last bug in there. When the valid exists, how can I create an "choice" that than the string length should not be zero. Then it should be the same range but length 5.